# How to convert .xarco to .urdf for Nvidia Isaac Sim?

Tags: ros, urdf, nvidia-isaac

I recently got into ROS2 and simulating robots and I started with the official Nvidia guide that [talks about the turtlerobot3](https://docs.omniverse.nvidia.com/isaacsim/latest/tutorial_ros2_turtlebot.html). I downloaded ROS2 Humble (for Ubuntu 22.04) and everything according to [their guide](https://docs.omniverse.nvidia.com/isaacsim/latest/install_ros.html#isaac-sim-app-install-ros), but when I git cloned the repo and **tried the xacro command to convert .xarco to .urdf for Isaac Sim**, I get the following error:
[image: Error]
Why isn't it detecting the "turtlebot_description" folder?

These are the commands I run every time I open the terminal (I should place them in bashrc so that I don't have to do this again and again):

```
source /opt/ros/humble/setup.bash
export TURTLEBOT3_MODEL=burger
cd .../urdf
xacro turtlebot3_burger.urdf.xacro > turtle1.urdf
```

And then it gives me this:
`"package not found: "package 'turtlebot3_description' not found, searching: ['/opt/ros/humble']"`

And I even tried placing the file in **$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH** so that ROS can find it with:
`export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/user1/codes/turtlebot3/turtlebot3/:/opt/ros/humble/share`

And if I do
`echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`
I get:
`/user1/codes/turtlebot3/turtlebot3/:/opt/ros/humble/share`
**Which is correct!** It should detect the turtlebot_description within the turtlebot3 folder. But it doesn't. So what am I doing wrong?

In the Nvidia docs, they do mention that we should place any package dependencies in the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH, but they don't mention *how* we're even supposed to do that...
[image: Docs]